# Yocto OEL x86-64 build Error

Tags: cross-platform, embedded-linux, x86-64, yocto, bitbake

I am building OEL for x86 and completed all steps as per the prerequisites http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html and further steps from github.com/OpenEneaLinux/oel.

I am running the script "./build_lng-x86-64.sh" but the following errors are thrown. The same error keeps repeating. Has anyone experienced anything similar ?

[OEL build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SL7d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix from comparing openjdk-common in dora branch vs openjdk-common in master branch. Please modify as needed. The files would be located in `/meta-java/openjdk/openjdk-common.inc`

Dora branch with error:
`ICEDTEA_VERSION = "${@bb.parse.BBHandler.vars_from_file(d.getVar('FILE'),d)[1].split("-")[1] or '1.0'}"`

Master branch:
`ICEDTEA_VERSION = "${@bb.parse.BBHandler.vars_from_file(d.getVar('FILE', False),d)[1].split("-")[1] or '1.0'}"`